# Redis-cli verbose mode

Tags: http, redis, redis-cli, verbose

I was trying to access the remote Redis instance using redis-cli -h and -p parameters.
Every time I hit send nothing seems to happen for over a minute. So, I don't even know ether it is a slow response from a server or an error from either side. Quick googling doesn't show any results for the

> redis-cli verbose

mode, but might be there is some way to somehow get more information using some flag? Is there some other way to troubleshoot the connection to the remote Redis instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. But if you have access to the remote server you can do some investigation. If that's the case, log in to the remote server and:

- Reconfigure [`loglevel debug`](https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/) for max instance logging.
- Run [`monitor`](https://redis.io/commands/monitor/) to watch all commands being sent to the Redis instance.

Now you can run your local command and go back to the remote server and inspect the log file and monitor command for any useful information.

These settings comes with a performance cost and should only be enabled in specific situations.